# Is it more performant to use specific selectors?

Tags: css

I'm working in a stylesheet that has a pattern like this:

```
.the-widget { foo: bar; }
.the-widget .some-thing { foo: bar; }
.the-widget .some-thing .some-other-thing { foo: bar; }
```

Which can make it easier to keep track of styles but it doesn't seem to scale well. I would prefer to just do:

```
.the-widget .some-other-thing { foo: bar }
```

and cut out the middle man. I know there are a lot of different opinions on how to architect a stylesheet so I'm asking if there are any objective advantages to using detailed selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you want to share a "sub-style" across the application. If you don't foresee that being a need for your particular case your desire to cut out the middle man is sensible and strongly defining the selector would result in less potential naming errors. It's really a matter of preference. Some folks stick to less is best methods. Again review your application and take the best route that makes sense to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The performance differences between the three examples you posted are negligible. (a critical-eyed Google search would likely substantiate my statement…)

And the last example is perfectly fine. As a general rule it's good to have as little specificity as needed in CSS, otherwise you'll soon be littering your code with `!important` statements or spending hours looking for some overriding rule somewhere in your code.

Comment: You provide great explanation. Thing also worth mentioning is that you should use more specific operators instead of using normal nesting. Of course when you have a way of doing your code with them. .the-widget .some-other-thing { foo: bar } will render way slower than .the-widget > .some-other-thing { foo: bar }

Comment: `.the-widget > .some-other-thing` is faster because the search for the parent (`.the-widget`) of `.some-other-thing` will stop at the first parent (whether there's a match or not) without needing to traverse the whole DOM tree up the `html` root. **However** unless you are coding a page with a huge DOM tree, no human will be able to perceive any performance difference when using `parent > child` selectors.